# Ошибка при импорте react-dom в tsx файл

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Текст ошибки:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dom'. implicitly has an 'any' type.

Ошибка появилась после того, как я установил `react-router-dom`, при этом ни разу его не импортировав.

Как я пытался решить эту проблему:

1. Добавил в **tsconfig** запись: `"noImplicitAny": false`.
2. Установил `@types/react-router`.

Как результат - эффекта никакого, ошибка осталась.
Буду рад вашей помощи :)

Comment: Ошибка пропадает, если вместо import использовать require. Но не понятно, что делать с import

Comment: всё зависит от того как вы запускаете приложение, вебпак или что там у вас.

Comment: react-scripts start

Comment: вариантов несколько:

1. использовать https://codesandbox.io
2. отредактировать вопрос, хотябы добавить содержимое `package.json`
3. создать проект или "gist" на github с минимальным воспроизводимым примером( конфиг, файл с ошибкой и т.д.) https://gist.github.com
4. `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

Comment: подробнее про 4 пункт тут https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/